# How to remove redundant encryption layers in Kubuntu 20.10?

Tags: kubuntu, password, encryption

Seems that I have two layers of encryption on my machine:

1. Operating system encryption: Password entered on Boot screen
2. Hard drive encryption: While my SSD loads fine, everytime I start my computer I need to enter a password to unlock the HDD. Checking the "Save password" option doesn't work

Is this the expected behavior that everyone with an encrypted computer uses? Isn't it sufficient to simply have the Boot-level encryption?

**How do I remove the encryption on my HDD?**

1. [image: Boot Password]
   2.[image: HDD Password]

Comment: Could you please share a photo/screenshot of both password prompts? This could help to identify which layers of encryption are being used and how to configure them to your likes. Besides, is that HDD an internal drive or an external USB drive?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it's expected (if you enabled drive encryption) and no, NOT redundant.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just entering the decryption password and the user's login password? The login password does not encrypt anything.

Comment: Images have been added. The HDD is an internal drive. The user's login is another separete layer that I have disabled.

What is the Boot password for? Is it not sufficient to have the HDD encrypted?

Comment: That is not a boot password. That would be a 3rd question asking for a password  ;-) That 2nd one is the kde daemon, not related to encryption; that is only the 1st image, and that one you need to authenticate with Kwallet (once per installation) and if you do not it will keep asking for it. Same with wifi network and networkmanager: password will be blank until you authenticate

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, only the 1st password is related to encryption.

**The solution is to authenticated Kwallet.**

Once Kwallet is configured in System Settings, the KDE Daemon password **WILL** save on that second login screen.